# Notation $\sum_{k \neq k'}$: is the order important?

Tags: notation, index-notation

I am reading [The Elements of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/ElemStatLearn/).

At pag. 309 the Gini index is defined as:

$$ \text{Gini} = \sum_{k \neq k'} \hat{p}_{mk} \hat{p}_{mk'} $$

where the index $k = {1,2,\dots,K}$.

In case $K=2$, does the notation implies

$$ \text{Gini} = \hat{p}_{m1} \hat{p}_{m2} $$

Or is it

$$ \text{Gini} = \hat{p}_{m1} \hat{p}_{m2} + \hat{p}_{m2} \hat{p}_{m1} = 2 \hat{p}_{m1} \hat{p}_{m2}$$

Is the order important?

Is this kind of notation "officially" defined? Where is it used?

Comment: For finite sums the order doesn't matter.

Comment: @Gae.S. so the second formula is correct and the first one is wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's the second one. The notation you are seeing is short for $$\sum_{\{(k,k')\in\{1,\cdots, K\}\times\{1,\cdots,K\}\,:\, k\ne k'\}}\widehat p_{mk}\widehat p_{mk'}$$ which idicates the sum over the pairs in the set indicated. That has been abbreviated to the point of just indicating the "non-obvious" condition to impose on the dummy variables that serve as indexes of summation. Abbreviations such as this one are widely used, though it's up to the writer to decide how extensive the abbreviation should be while still preserving clarity.

Comment: @Gae.S. thank you very much for the full notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \sum_{k \neq k'} \hat{p}_{mk} \hat{p}_{mk'}= \hat{p}_{m1} \hat{p}_{m2} + \hat{p}_{m2} \hat{p}_{m1}. $$

$$ \sum_{k \lt k'} \hat{p}_{mk} \hat{p}_{mk'}= \hat{p}_{m1} \hat{p}_{m2}.$$